# String function on a pandas series

Tags: python, string, pandas, series

I wanted to used the below string functions text.lower for a Pandas series instead of from a text file. Tried different methods to convert the series to list and then string,, but no luck. Still I am not able to use the below function directly. Help is much appreciated.

```
def words(text): 
    return re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())
WORDS = Counter(words(open('some.txt').read()))
```

Comment: What kind of data do you have and what output to you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) by your function:

```
s = pd.Series(['Aasa dsad d','GTH rr','SSD'])
print (s)
0    Aasa dsad d
1         GTH rr
2            SSD
dtype: object

def words(text): 
    return re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())

print (s.apply(words))
0    [aasa, dsad, d]
1          [gth, rr]
2              [ssd]
dtype: object
```

But in pandas is better use [`str.lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) and [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html), because also working with `NaN`s:

```
print (s.str.lower().str.findall(r'\w+'))
0    [aasa, dsad, d]
1          [gth, rr]
2              [ssd]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series(['word', 'Word', 'WORD', 'other_word'])
counter = Counter(series.apply(lambda x: x.lower()))
print(counter)
```